# invalid initialization of non-const

Tags: c++, классы, ссылки, перегрузка-операторов

```
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

class complex {
    double re, im;
public:
    complex(double = 0, double = 0);
    ~complex();

    complex operator+(complex&);
    complex operator-(complex&);
    complex operator*(complex&);
    complex operator/(complex&);
    complex operator^(unsigned);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream &, complex&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &, complex &);
};

complex::complex(double r, double i)
{
    re = r;
    im = i;
}

complex::~complex() { }

complex complex::operator+(complex&y)
{
    return complex(re + y.re, im + y.im);
}

complex complex::operator-(complex&y)
{
    return complex(re - y.re, im - y.im);
}

complex complex::operator*(complex&y)
{
    return complex(re*y.re - im*y.im, re*y.im + im*y.re);
}

complex complex::operator/(complex&y)
{
    double r1 = re;
    double i1 = im;
    double r2 = y.re;
    double i2 = y.im;
    return complex((r1*r2 - i1*i1) / (r2*r2 + i2*i2), (-r1*i2 + i1*r2) / (r2*r2 + i2*i2));
}

complex complex::operator^(unsigned n)
{
    complex y(1, 0);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            y = y*(*this);
    return y;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& is, complex& x)
{
    char c;
    cin >> c;
    assert(c == '(');
    cin >> x.re;
    cin >> c;
    assert(c == ',');
    cin >> x.im;
    cin >> c;
    assert(c == ')');
    return is;

}

ostream& operator<<(ostream&os, complex&x)
{
    os << '(' << x.re << ',' << x.im << ')' << endl;
    return os;
}

int main(){

    complex a(1, 1);
    complex b(1, 1);
    complex c(1, 1);
    complex x;

    cout << "Введите комплексное число в формате: (re,im) ->";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "Результат =" << a*(x ^ 2)) + b*x + c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

На линуксе выводит ошибку:

> invalid initialization of non-const

для строки:

```
cout << "Результат =" << a*(x ^ 2) + b*x + c << endl;
```

Саму программу скопировал с *Windows*, ошибки исправил, только эту выдает. В чем здесь проблема? И как можно ее решить? На *Visual Studio* работала нормально.

Comment: Попробуйте в следующий раз всё же создать [mcve].

Comment: А что у вас за чехарда с балансом скобок в этой строке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявите данные операторы следующим образом

```
complex operator+( const complex&) const;
complex operator-(const complex&) const;
complex operator*(const complex&) const;
complex operator/( const complex&) const;
complex operator ^( unsigned int ) const;
friend ostream& operator << (ostream &, const complex &);
```

Нельзя связывать временные объекты с неконстантной lvalue ссылкой.

Обратите внимание , что конструктор класса является преобразующим конструктором. Поэтому у вас будет работать выражение `complex + double`, как, например,

```
complex a( 10, 10 );
complex b = a + 10;
```

Но не будет работать выражение `double + complex`

```
complex a( 10, 10 );
complex b = 10 + a; // ошибка компиляции
```

так как ваши операторы являются членами класса. Вы могли бы их объявить как отдельные функции, не являющиеся членами класса, которые принимают два аргумента. Например,

```
friend complex operator +( const complex &lhs, const complex &rhs )
{
    return complex( lhs.re + rhs.re, lhs.im + rhs.im );
}
```

В этом случае второе выражение было бы также верным.

Эта дружественная функция может быть определена как в самом классе, и тогда при использовании оператора будет применен зависящий от аргумента поиск (ADL), либо вне класса.

Что касается Visual Studio, то его компилятор имеет собственные расширения языка (которые активизированы по умолчанию; вы можете отключить эту опцию в настройках компилятора, и тогда будет выдано сообщение об ошибке), которые порой противоречат стандарту C++. Не стоит полагаться на эти расширения языка компилятора C++ Visual Studio, так как код будет не переносимым.

**EDIT:** Так как у вас возникают трудности правильно набрать код, то приведу для вас рабочий вариант программы. Я не проверял, определены ли правильно операторы с точки зрения математики.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

class complex 
{
private:    
    double re, im;

public:
    complex( double = 0, double = 0 );
    ~complex();

    complex operator +( const complex & ) const;
    complex operator -( const complex & ) const;
    complex operator *( const complex & ) const;
    complex operator /( const complex & ) const;
    complex operator ^( unsigned int ) const;
    friend std::istream & operator >>( std::istream &, complex & );
    friend std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &, const complex & );
};

complex::complex( double r, double i ) : re( r ), im( i )
{
}

complex::~complex() { }

complex complex::operator +( const complex &c ) const
{
    return complex( re + c.re, im + c.im );
}

complex complex::operator -( const complex &c ) const
{
    return complex( re - c.re, im - c.im );
}

complex complex::operator *( const complex &c ) const
{
    return complex( re * c.re - im * c.im, re * c.im + im * c.re );
}

complex complex::operator /( const complex & c ) const
{
    double r1 = re;
    double i1 = im;
    double r2 = c.re;
    double i2 = c.im;
    return complex( ( r1 * r2 - i1 * i1 ) / ( r2 * r2 + i2 * i2 ), 
                    (-r1 * i2 + i1 * r2 ) / ( r2 * r2 + i2 * i2 ) );
}

complex complex::operator ^( unsigned int n ) const
{
    complex c( 1, 0 );

    for ( unsigned int i = 1; i <= n; i++ ) c = c * *this;

    return c;
}

std::istream & operator >>( std::istream &is, complex &c )
{
    char ch;

    is >> ch;
    assert( ch == '(' );

    is >> c.re;

    is >> ch;
    assert( ch == ',' );

    is >> c.im;

    is >> ch;
    assert( ch == ')' );

    return is;
}

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const complex &c )
{
    return os << '(' << c.re << ',' << c.im << ')';
}

int main() 
{
    complex a(1, 1);
    complex b(1, 1);
    complex c(1, 1);
    complex x;

    std::cout << "Введите комплексное число в формате: (re,im) ->";
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "x = " << x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "x ^ 2 = " << ( x ^ 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a * ( x ^ 2 ) = " << a * ( x ^ 2 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b * x = " << b * x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "a * ( x ^ 2 ) + b * x = " << a * ( x ^ 2 ) + b * x << std::endl;


    std::cout << "Результат =" << a * ( x ^ 2 ) + b * x + c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если ввести значение `(10,10)`, то вывод будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Введите комплексное число в формате: (re,im) ->(10,10)
x = (10,10)
x ^ 2 = (0,200)
a * ( x ^ 2 ) = (-200,200)
b * x = (0,20)
a * ( x ^ 2 ) + b * x = (-200,220)
Результат =(-199,221)
```

Comment: Бинарные операторы лучше вообще не делать членами.

Comment: Visual C++ честно выдал предупреждение о нестандартном расширении. Другое дело, что эти предупреждения часто игнорируют, гм... не очень педантичные программисты :)

Comment: Ошибок только больше стало.

Comment: @Владимир Ошибок больше стало только по той причине, что вы их допускаете. Объявления операторов в классе и при определении вне класса должны совпадать.

Comment: @Владимир Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Для таких простых классов с семантикой значения и малым размером лучше делать операторы свободными функциями (в силу семантики), и даже, возможно, с передачей по значению (в силу малости - 2 `double` скопировать против разыменований адресов (ссылка работает через адрес) - неизвестно, что выиграет... Как минимум, стоит выполнить несколько хронометражей):

```
friend complex operator+(complex a, complex b) {
    return complex(a.re+b.re,a.im+b.im); 
}
```

**Update** Провел хронометраж. VC++ 2015.

На 32 разрядах константная ссылка быстрее примерно в 1.5 раза. На 64 разрядах одинаково. В принципе, более-менее понятно, почему. Ну, значит, нужно

```
friend complex operator+(const complex& a, const complex& b) {
    return complex(a.re+b.re,a.im+b.im); 
}
```

Comment: [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_arith3) всё же использует ссылку, но стоит заметить, что он  шаблонный.

Comment: @alexolut Цена обобщенности... Сейчас интереса для проведу пару измерений.

Comment: Для явных специализаций `float, double, long double` тоже ссылки, но операторы присваивания для действительной (Re) части используют передачу по значению.